# Publish A WPF Application To An Asp.Net Website

Tags: asp.net, wpf, iis

I'm using Visual Studio (VS) Professional Edition 2010 and IIS 7.  I'd like to publish a wpf application for download from a website.  But for some reason, when I go to Build > Publish in VS, select a publishing location, select that users will install the application from a website, and then try to browse to a URL on my machine, VS gives me an error message saying:

> To access local IIS Web sites, you
>   must install the following IIS
>   components:
>
> IIS 6 Metabase and IIS 6
>   Configuration Compatibility ASP.NET

I'm not really sure why this is happening.  I'm running IIS 7 on my computer, and it was my understanding that Metabase has been rendered obsolete in the latest version of IIS...  Does anyone know what's going on?

Many thanks in advance,

Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why these components are needed, but they actually are. Some features like the FTP server are still handled by IIS 6 or installed separately.
See [this blog](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bursteg/archive/2007/02/24/Using-ClickOnce-on-Vista-and-IIS-7.aspx) that explains how to do it.

Comment: Thanks Matt, that's great!  There's no way I would have figured that out on my own....